# Newbie - TableView Functions not getting accessed and tableView not loading

Tags: swift, uitableview

I set this up in another sample project and it works.  I know there is data there as it prints out below.

---

import UIKit
import CoreData

class GameDataTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
@IBOutlet weak var GameDataTableView: UITableView!
 var gameStats = [NSManagedObject]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return gameStats.count
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    print("ahere I am")

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)as! CustomCell

    let game = gameStats[indexPath.row]

    cell.yourTeamSaveLbl!.text = game.valueForKey("yourTeamSave")as? String
    cell.yourScoreSaveLbl!.text = game.valueForKey("yourTeamScoreSave")as? String


    return cell
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TeamStats")


    do {
        let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        gameStats = results as! [NSManagedObject]

       //added line here:
       self.tableView.reloadData()

        print(gameStats.count)
        print("**********************")

        for item in gameStats{

            print(item.valueForKey("gameDateSave")as! String)
            print("------")
            print(item.valueForKey("yourTeamSave")as? String)
            print(item.valueForKey("yourTeamScoreSave")as? String)

            print(item.valueForKey("opponentSave")as? String)
            print(item.valueForKey("opponentScoreSave")as? String)
            print(item.valueForKey("pplGoalSave")as? String)
            print(item.valueForKey("shGoalSave")as? String)
            print(item.valueForKey("shotSave")as? String)
            print(item.valueForKey("passPercentSave")as? String)
            print(item.valueForKey("offSideSave")as? String)
            print(item.valueForKey("icingSave")as? String)
            print(item.valueForKey("homeGoalSave")as? String)
            print(item.valueForKey("savePercentSave")as? String)

            print("**********************")
        }



    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Coiuld not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u set "gameStats" at viewDidAppear, so you have to reload tableview to get data refreshed and appeared on your tableview

so after

```
gameStats = results as! [NSManagedObject]
```

you need to add

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: I added the line as directed, now I get and error - Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'

Comment: what is print(gameStats) output ?

Answer (score 0):

Writing new answer since I can't comment yet. It seems that when you set "gameStats" you are trying to reload the tableView with "self.tableView.reloadData()" but at the start of your code you referenced your tableView as "GameDataTableView". Try changing "self.tableView.reloadData()" with "self.GameDataTableView.reloadData()" see if it helps.

Comment: It seems to be trying now.  I get the following output with an error at the bottom, I believe I have to look at my class setup.  I did put data in every variable:   2016-04-18 13:03:56.041 TeamStats[4403:2413969] CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named '' for entity 'TeamStats'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
1
**********************
Apr 18, 2016, 12:45 PM
------
Optional("Bantam A2")
Optional("3")
Optional("Tryouts ")
Optional("1")
Optional("1")
Optional("1")
Optional("4")
Optional("Pass % 50.00")
Optional("1")
Optional("1")

Comment: Optional("1")
Optional("Save % 0.50")
**********************
ahere I am
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)  - It is complaining at the second line here:  cell.yourTeamSaveLbl!.text = game.valueForKey("yourTeamSave")as? String
        cell.yourScoreSaveLbl!.text = game.valueForKey("yourTeamScoreSave")as? String

Comment: Your fix works.  THANK YOU Very Much.  I already spent a lot of time on this to no avail.  I commented out th problem line above and I see data in my tableView.

Comment: No problem, glad to be bit of help. :) Happy coding.